# Is there any way to make my iPhone sync calendars with iCloud periodically?

Tags: ios, icloud, calendar

I have an iPhone and an iPad, both with iOS 6.1. I use iCloud for calendar syncing between them and my Mac. For whatever reason, the iOS devices don’t sync calendars with iCloud unless and until I open the Calendar app on the device. Is there any way to change this behavior so that iOS checks for calendar changes without my intervention?

(This is very annoying for two reasons: I set alarms on events frequently, but each time I do this on my computer I have to remember to launch Calendar on my phone or else it won’t know about the new event and it won’t remind me. Moreover, I don’t even use Calendar—I use Fantastical on the phone and Calvetica on the iPad—so it’s out of my way even to launch the Calendar app.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate to: **Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Fetch New Data**

And set:

- Push = ON
- Fetch = (as often as you like)

Move to **Advanced**, and set iCloud to **Push**

Comment: How do I get to the Push menu in iOS 10?

Answer (score 1):

Checklist:

1. Check your Calendars setting on iOS (accessible from the
   Settings->iCloud) by ensuring your iCloud account details in
   correct. Then
2. Check the Calendars Sync setting on iOS (accessible from Settings->"Mail, Contacts, Calendars" settings on iOS). Also touch the > symbol to the right of "Fetch New Data" setting to ensure Push is ON and set to fetch at an interval you prefer (every 15 minutes, etc.) You can even use the Advanced section to select which email you want to Push or Fetch.